# How many libraries can i have in the same angular workspace?

Tags: path, architecture, shared-libraries, angular-cli, workspace

Can I have more than one library in the same angular workspace?
For Example:

```
lib-shared/
    projects/
          lib1
          lib2
          lib3
```

I tried to create a second library in my worskspace and import it into my app getting the following errors:

```
    core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingStartIndex' of null
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14822)
    at LsLibHeadToolbarComponent_Template (template.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at renderView (core.js:7264)
    at renderComponent (core.js:8520)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:7138)
    at renderView (core.js:7289)
    at renderComponent (core.js:8520)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:7138)
    at renderView (core.js:7289)
```

I noticed a strange thing: in the first library I created (working) in the src folder there are the files:

1. -public-api.ts
2. -test.ts

instead in the second library there are the files:

1. -projects.ts
2. -test.ts

this is my angular.json of workspace:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ls-lib-menu": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/ls-lib-menu",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/ls-lib-menu/src",
      "prefix": "ls-lib-menu",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-menu/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/ls-lib-menu/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-menu/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/ls-lib-menu/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-menu/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/ls-lib-menu/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/ls-lib-menu/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/ls-lib-menu/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ls-lib-head-toolbar": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/src",
      "prefix": "ls-lib-head-toolbar",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ls-lib-menu",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

I imported both libraries into the app.module.ts file:

```
import { LsLibMenuModule } from '../../../../../ls-lib-shared/projects/ls-lib-menu/src/public-api';
import { LsLibHeadToolbarModule } from '../../../../../ls-lib-shared/projects/ls-lib-head-toolbar/src/projects';
```

Comment: Seems like something you could have answered on your own by simply *trying* it.

Comment: He thanks for the extra info. I do not see an `app` inside the workspace posted above. Only 2 libraries. Where are you importing 'the 2nd library'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many as you want. Just make sure you add them to the angular.json, but if you generate the library with the angular-CLI this will be done automatically.

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: if i try to export and use a second library in my app i get the following errors:

core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingStartIndex' of null
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14822)
    at LsLibHeadToolbarComponent_Template (template.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at renderView (core.js:7264)
    at renderComponent (core.js:8520)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:7138)
    at renderView (core.js:7289)
    at renderComponent (core.js:8520)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:7138)
    at renderView (core.js:7289)

Comment: Could you extend your question with the actual error that you are getting? Try to give us as much information as you can that could help us solve the problem. Adding the angular.json, how you import the library, these kinds of things will help. If there are more things you think will help us please add them too.